# Hide Header Logo on Mobile in Chamilo LMS

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

i am trying to hide my header logo on mobile so i put the following code in my css but it did not work,
someone tel me which code should i put in css or which directory of chamilo LMS?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px)
div#logo {
display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: did you forget opening curly braces of media query?

Comment: please check this link https://www.internater.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no id called logo in your html. Try this instead:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .logo {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this in my css but but it not worked. any other way?